# Keep Sum column at bottom when Header is clicked on DataGrid in Windows Application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, sorting, datagridview

I have a DataGridView which takes a datasource from a Datatable. I have added in a new row into the datatable which adds the total values of the Columns and this displays fine until the Header is clicked and then the data is sorted and my Totals Row appears half the way up my grid!

I have been looking for a solution for this for hours now and can't seem to find anything concrete.  I've seen people overriding the SortCompare method, but this doesn't get used when there is a datasource. I've seen mentions of a Footer, however this seems to be primarily ASP, but I have seen bits and pieces of broken code for windows applications.

Basically all I want to do is have my count column at the bottom of the grid and it stays there when I click on the headers! I thought this would be a fairly straight forward bit of work but it's proving to be tricky.

My grid is made up of 4 or 5 main columns of data, Name, Position etc and the rest of the columns are dates based on a filter, so those are fairly dynamic.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is handle the `Sorted` event, essentially pinning your desired row to the bottom when a sort occurs.  Note that the new empty row *must* always be the very last row, but that's trivial.

First, you'll want to add a tag to your desired row when you create it.

```
DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
row.CreateCells(this.dataGridView1);
/* Your code to sum columns... */
row.Tag = "Totals";
row.ReadOnly = true;
this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
```

Then handle the `Sorted` event.  I've factored out the code for the sorted event into another method, you'll see why.

```
private void dataGridView1_Sorted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.LockBottomRow();
}

private void LockBottomRow()
{
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
  {
    if (row.Tag != null && row.Tag.ToString() == "Totals")
    {
      int index = this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2;
      this.dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
      this.dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(index, row);
    }
  }
}
```

This will lock your Totals row below all other filled rows.  As a bonus, I thought it would be nice when typing in the new row, if it instead of being added after your Totals row and needing to be resorted, we just handled that in the `RowsAdded` event.

```
private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
  DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

  if (row.Tag == null || row.Tag.ToString() != "Totals")
  {

    if (this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null)
    {
      this.LockBottomRow();
      this.dataGridView1.BeginEdit(false);
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!  I enjoyed experimenting to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks OBW.  The tag gets lost before it hits the sorting unfortunately. Also, the datagridview is bound so Rows.Insert won't work. 

What I did do was take the datasource, push it into a datatable and then add the column and then use that datatable as the datasource, which works...but it looks like it's sorting the datagrid after this.  I need to find a way to add this row back in after it has sorted.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation (and a need to accomplish the same task), I understand what you meant. With a `DataTable` as the `DataSource`, the data seems to have a late sort.  Digging in I noticed that the source itself is never changed - the order remains the same although the displayed data is sorted: hence even when adding the sum row to the end of the source, it still gets sorted.

**My solution:** Inherit from the `DataGridView` class, override the `Sort` method, and force the `DataTable` items to re-order according to the sort order by removing and re-adding the items in that order. Doing this, the default `Sort` must be prevented. As an extra, I also handled the `HeaderCell` indicating it's sorted still, and allowed for multiple sum columns.

**The new DataGridView:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestSortWithSum
{
  public class DataTableSumSortableDGV : DataGridView
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Column index for the sum label.
    /// </summary>
    private int labelColumnIndex = -1;

    /// <summary>
    /// Text for the sum label.
    /// </summary>
    private string labelColumnText = string.Empty;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor. Initialize sort direction and subscribe event.
    /// </summary>
    public DataTableSumSortableDGV()
      : base()
    {
      this.SumColumnIndices = new ObservableCollection<int>();
      this.Direction = string.Empty;
      this.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
      this.AllowUserToAddRowsChanged += DataTableSumSortableDGV_AllowUserToAddRowsChanged;
      this.DataBindingComplete += DataTableSumSortableDGV_DataBindingComplete;
      this.DataSourceChanged += DataTableSumSortableDGV_DataSourceChanged;
      this.SumColumnIndices.CollectionChanged += SumColumnIndices_CollectionChanged;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Text for the sum label.
    /// </summary>
    public string LabelColumnText
    {
      get
      {
        return this.labelColumnText;
      }

      set
      {
        Action action = () =>
          {
            if (this.HasSumColumns())
            {
              this.RemoveSumRow();
            }

            this.labelColumnText = value;

            if (this.HasSumColumns())
            {
              this.AddSumRow();
            }
          };

        this.MakeInternalChanges(action);
      }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Column index for the sum label.
    /// </summary>
    public int LabelColumnIndex
    {
      get
      {
        return this.labelColumnIndex;
      }

      set
      {
        Action action = () =>
          {
            if (this.HasSumColumns())
            {
              this.RemoveSumRow();
            }

            this.labelColumnIndex = value;

            if (this.HasSumColumns())
            {
              this.AddSumRow();
            }
          };

        this.MakeInternalChanges(action);
      }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Column indices for the sum(s).
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<int> SumColumnIndices { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The DataTable sort direction.
    /// </summary>
    private string Direction { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The DataTable source.
    /// </summary>
    private DataTable DataTable { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The DataTable sum row.
    /// </summary>
    private DataRow SumRow { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// DataGridView Sort method.
    /// If DataSource is DataTable, special sort the source.
    /// Else normal sort.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dataGridViewColumn">The DataGridViewColumn to sort by header click.</param>
    /// <param name="direction">The desired sort direction.</param>
    public override void Sort(DataGridViewColumn dataGridViewColumn, System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection direction)
    {
      if (this.HasSumColumns())
      {
        Action action = () =>
        {
          this.RemoveSumRow();

          string col = this.DataTable.Columns[dataGridViewColumn.Index].ColumnName;

          if (!this.Direction.Contains(col))
          {
            this.ClearOldSort();
          }

          string sort = this.Direction.Contains("ASC") ? "DESC" : "ASC";
          this.Direction = string.Format("{0} {1}", col, sort);

          this.SortRows(this.Direction);
          this.AddSumRow();
        };

        this.MakeInternalChanges(action);
        dataGridViewColumn.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = this.Direction.Contains("ASC") ? SortOrder.Ascending : SortOrder.Descending;
      }
      else
      {
        this.DataTable.DefaultView.Sort = string.Empty;
        base.Sort(dataGridViewColumn, direction);
      }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// DataBindingComplete event handler.
    /// Add the sum row when DataSource = a new DataTable.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">This DataGridView object.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs.</param>
    private void DataTableSumSortableDGV_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
      this.DataTable = (DataTable)this.DataSource;
      this.AddInitialSumRow();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// For a new DataSource, start with a fresh SumRow.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The DataGridView object.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The EventArgs.</param>
    void DataTableSumSortableDGV_DataSourceChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      this.SumRow = null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Prevent users from adding a row as this is DataSourced and rows should be added to the DataTable instead.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The DataGridView object.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The EventArgs.</param>
    private void DataTableSumSortableDGV_AllowUserToAddRowsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (this.AllowUserToAddRows)
      {
        this.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
      }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The sum columns have been altered. Reflect the change immediately.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The SumColumnIndices object.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs.</param>
    private void SumColumnIndices_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      this.AddInitialSumRow();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add the sum row for the first time: once the DataTable is sourced and
    /// the label column index, label text, and sum column index are set.
    /// </summary>
    private void AddInitialSumRow()
    {
      if (this.HasSumColumns())
      {
        Action action = () =>
        {
          this.RemoveSumRow();
          this.AddSumRow();
        };

        this.MakeInternalChanges(action);
      }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add the sum row to the DataTable as a ReadOnly row.
    /// </summary>
    private void AddSumRow()
    {
      List<decimal> sum = this.CreateListOfSums();
      List<int> exclude = new List<int>();

      for (int row = 0; row < this.DataTable.Rows.Count; row++)
      {
        for (int index = 0; index < this.SumColumnIndices.Count; index++)
        {
          try
          {
            int col = this.SumColumnIndices[index];
            decimal value = 0;

            if (Decimal.TryParse(this.DataTable.Rows[row].ItemArray[col].ToString(), out value))
            {
              sum[index] += value;
            }
            else if (!exclude.Contains(col))
            {
              exclude.Add(col);
            }
          }
          catch (RowNotInTableException)
          {
            continue;
          }
        }
      }

      object[] items = this.CreateItemsArray(this.DataTable.Columns.Count, sum, exclude);

      if (Array.TrueForAll<object>(items, item => { return item == null; }))
      {
        this.SumRow = null;
      }
      else
      {
        this.SumRow = this.DataTable.NewRow();
        this.SumRow.ItemArray = items;
        this.DataTable.Rows.Add(this.SumRow);

        if (this.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
          this.Rows[this.Rows.Count - 1].ReadOnly = true;
        } 
      }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clear the old sort string and any set glyph directions in header cells.
    /// </summary>
    private void ClearOldSort()
    {
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Direction))
      {
        string[] sortVals = this.Direction.Split(new char[] { ' ' }); // [ "ColName", "ASC/DESC" ]
        this.Columns[sortVals[0]].HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = SortOrder.None;
      }

      this.Direction = string.Empty;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create the items array for the new sum row.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="length">The array length for the items.</param>
    /// <param name="sum">The list of sums.</param>
    /// <param name="exclude">The list of sum columns that aren't actually sum columns.</param>
    /// <returns>Object array for the sum row.</returns>
    private object[] CreateItemsArray(int length, List<decimal> sum, List<int> exclude)
    {
      object[] items = new object[length];

      if (this.IsValidIndex())
      {
        items[this.LabelColumnIndex] = this.LabelColumnText;
      }

      for (int index = 0; index < this.SumColumnIndices.Count; index++)
      {
        int col = this.SumColumnIndices[index];

        if (!exclude.Contains(col))
        {
          items[col] = sum[index];
        }
      }
      return items;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a list of sums for each sum column index.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A new list of sums.</returns>
    private List<decimal> CreateListOfSums()
    {
      List<decimal> sum = new List<decimal>();

      foreach (int index in this.SumColumnIndices)
      {
        sum.Add(0m);
      }

      return sum;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determine if the index is a valid column for the label.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>True if the index is valid.</returns>
    private bool IsValidIndex()
    {
      return
        this.LabelColumnIndex >= 0 &&
        this.LabelColumnIndex < this.DataTable.Columns.Count &&
        this.DataTable.Columns[this.LabelColumnIndex].DataType == typeof(string);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Unsubscribe the DataBindingComplete event handler, call internal sorting changes,
    /// then re-subscribe to the DataBindingComplete event handler. This must be done
    /// with any item removal/addition to the DataSource DataTable to prevent recursion
    /// resulting in a Stack Overflow.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="operation">The internal changes to be made to the DataSource.</param>
    private void MakeInternalChanges(Action operation)
    {
      this.DataBindingComplete -= DataTableSumSortableDGV_DataBindingComplete;
      operation();
      this.DataBindingComplete += DataTableSumSortableDGV_DataBindingComplete;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Remove any existing sum row.
    /// </summary>
    private void RemoveSumRow()
    {
      if (this.SumRow != null)
      {
        this.DataTable.Rows.Remove(this.SumRow);
      }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determine if the grid has sum sortable columns.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// True if the source and sum column(s) exist.
    /// False if any one condition fails = sort as normal DataGridView.
    /// </returns>
    private bool HasSumColumns()
    {
      return this.DataTable != null && this.SumColumnIndices.Count > 0;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sort the DataTable by re-ordering the actual items.
    /// Get the sorted row order. For each sorted row,
    /// remove it from the original list, then re-add it to the end.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sort">The "ColumnName ASC/DESC" sort string.</param>
    private void SortRows(string sort)
    {
      DataRow[] sortedRows = this.DataTable.Select(string.Empty, sort);

      foreach (DataRow row in sortedRows)
      {
        object[] items = (object[])row.ItemArray.Clone();
        this.DataTable.Rows.Remove(row);
        this.DataTable.Rows.Add(items);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Example usage:**

```
namespace TestSortWithSum
{
    public partial class Form1: Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            DataTableSumSortableDGV dataGridView1 = new DataTableSumSortableDGV();
            dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = GetSumTable();
            dataGridView1.SumColumnIndices.Add(3);
            dataGridView1.SumColumnIndices.Add(4);
            dataGridView1.LabelColumnIndex = 2;
            dataGridView1.LabelColumnText = "Total";
            this.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);
        }

        private DataTable GetSumTable()
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            table.Columns.Add("Foo", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Bar", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(decimal));
            table.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(int));

            table.Rows.Add("Foo  1", "Bar  7", "Abcd", 1.11, 1);
            table.Rows.Add("Foo  2", "Bar  8", "Hijk", 2.22, 2);
            table.Rows.Add("Foo  3", "Bar  9", "Qrs", 3.33, 3);
            table.Rows.Add("Foo  4", "Bar 10", "W", 4.44, 4);
            table.Rows.Add("Foo  5", "Bar  1", "Y", 5.55, 5);
            table.Rows.Add("Foo  6", "Bar  2", "Z", 6.66, 1);
            table.Rows.Add("Foo  7", "Bar  3", "X", 7.77, 2);
            table.Rows.Add("Foo  8", "Bar  4", "Tuv", 8.88, 3);
            table.Rows.Add("Foo  9", "Bar  5", "Lmnop", 9.99, 4);
            table.Rows.Add("Foo 10", "Bar  6", "Efg", 1.11, 5);

            return table;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.